# Subprocess not picking up Awscli exclude and include filters

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3, aws-cli

I have this python script and it executes, but the "parameter" part is excluded. As a result, all files from "path" is downloaded to "target". It should ideally incorporate the "parameter" part as well, which contains the exclude & include filters.

How do I allow the "parameter" part of this script to execute?

I'm also open to workarounds in boto3, etc.

```
Import awscli    
Import os
Import time   

path = 's3://source/treasure/'
target = 'C:\\Home\\Day\\'
parameter = ' --recursive --exclude "*" --include "status.2018-'
monthlog = time.strftime("%m-%d") 
execute='aws s3 cp '+path+' '+target+''+parameter+''+monthlog+'.log"'

subprocess.run(['cmd','/c',execute])
```

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `shell=True` or break the arguments up into a list:

```
execute = ['aws', 's3', 'cp', path, target, '--recursive', '--exclude', '*', --include, 'status.2018-%m-%d.log']
```

Notice that you don't need to put quotes around `*` if not using `shell=True` as the quotes are only there to suppress shell expansion; if not using the shell you do not need to suppress that and can press the wildcard directly.